# Draw Bitmap on another Bitmap with same width and height

Tags: android, android-bitmap

there I want to overlay an `Bitmap` onto my another `Bitmap`. You can say, I want to draw a `Bitmap` on another `bitmap`.

Suppose that I have a `Bitmap` as:

And I want to draw another `bitmap` onto this bitmap "KEEP CALM AND CHECK YOUR WORK"! This will be **Bitmap 1**

[image]

The `Bitmap` I want to place on this `bitmap` is like an effect overlay as:
[image]

This will be **Bitmap 2**

---

### The Problem

I want to overlay **Bitmap 2** onto **Bitmap 1** say **Bitmap 2** should come above **Bitmap 1**.

The **Bitmap 2** Should get the width and height of the **Bitmap 1** to cover it all.

The **Bitmap 1** will be of any width and height but, I want the **Bitmap 2** should get the width and height of the **Bitmap 1** in any case.

My code problem is that it **crops** the **Bitmap 1** and overlay **Bitmap 2** onto it then. I mean the code is getting the **Bitmap 2** width and height!

---

### What I have done

```
public Bitmap overlay123(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
            Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2.getWidth(), bmp2.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
            float left =(bmp2.getWidth() - (bmp1.getWidth()*((float)bmp2.getHeight()/(float)bmp1.getHeight())))/(float)2.0;
            float bmp1newW = bmp1.getWidth()*((float)bmp2.getHeight()/(float)bmp1.getHeight());
            Bitmap bmp1new = getResizedBitmap(bmp1, bmp2.getHeight(), (int)bmp1newW);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1new, left ,0 , null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
            return bmOverlay;
        }

        public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
            int width = bm.getWidth();
            int height = bm.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
            return resizedBitmap;
}
```

---

Problem with the above code is that it crops or resizes **bitmap 1** width and height!

---

### Try 2

```
private Bitmap overlayer(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

---

Problem with code is that It always show the **Bitmap 2** in the top left corner with a smaller size!

---

I just need to know how can I place the **Bitmap 2** onto **Bitmap 1** getting width and height same as of **Bitmap 1**.

I am newbie to Bitmap Codes so I have no idea about it

Thanks in advace!

The final image should look like:
[image]

Comment: What do you do with the bitmap afterwards?

Comment: Did u try clearing the canvas.?

Comment: why dont you just use a `LayerDrawable`?

Comment: i have no idea how to do it with bitmaps

Comment: use two `BitmapDrawable`s as layers

Answer (score 2):

**MainActivity**  [**Output.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsZj5Nm9TCM&feature=youtu.be)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView Img;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.top);
                Bitmap bmt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back);
                Img.setImageBitmap(overlayer(bm, bmt));

            }
        });
    }
    private Bitmap overlayer(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**

[**Output result see here.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsZj5Nm9TCM&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i advice you to use your **Try2** as basis for further work.
But i would slightly modify the code to that:

```
private Bitmap overlayer(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, null, new Rect(0,0,bmp1.getWidth(),bmp1.getHeight()), new Paint());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, null, new Rect(0,0,bmp1.getWidth(),bmp1.getHeight()), new Paint());
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

I have used the constructor mentioned on the [android developer reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)) for drawing bitmaps. You define a new Recatangle, that servers as shape for scaling/drawing the bitmaps to the canvas. In your case, i am defining the rectangle with same size as your bitmap1. If you hand this recangle box over to the method, which is drawing the canvas, the canvas will scale the bitmap to that box size and draw it on the canvas.